# Use jQuery to fetch width of div x and apply same width to div y

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry

my question is hypothetical, I have no produced code to work with yet.

I have a web page with a centred grid, arranged using jQuery Masonry. My problem is one of aesthetics. Because masonry centres the grid, which is purposeful, the grid is often significantly thinner than the parent container, and so it does not align too well with elements in the header and footer. Similarly, sometimes the grid is allowed to expand beyond the width of the header, which looks even worse.

I have looked into using a script to resize fluid columns, though my grid contains images and the results were not nice. I am now thinking of, maybe a there is a small script which can detect and fetch the width of the masonry container at any single time, `#grid` (the width is dynamic of course and displayed inline) such as `<div id="grid" class="masonry" style="height: 408px; position: relative; width: 1368px;">` and then apply this same width to `#header`, `#footer`, and whatever else is requried to make the whole thing line up according to the grid width.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do this: simply put the header into the #container like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLjUJ/), the blue box centers and resizes as required. Maybe that's what you're after.

Comment: Yep, I tried that before, but actually it would have involved a few large changes to the css, the markup and another script I am using, all this seemed to put me off the idea at the time :) Anyway, I think I am going to experiment with this solution. Thanks

Comment: Sure, give it a try. Benefit of this is obviously having a nicely centered solution across devices.

Comment: Yes, you are right, having seen the demo it looks like a useful method for scaling down. Your suggestion is appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

Sure

```
var current_width = $("#grid").width();
$("#footer, #header").width(current_width);
```

or

```
$("#footer, #header").width($("#grid").width());
```

Now when the page is resized (also happens if the page is zoomed?) run the code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $("#footer, #header").width($("#grid").width());
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah, cool. It appears to be functional in parts, though the header does not seem to resize as effectively as the grid. I mean, when you actually drag the window to resize it, the header width does not update, it retains its previous size. Any ideas? Otherwise I can have a little play around with it, I guess I might be able to get it working.

Comment: you mean it doesnt get the new width at all? does it really have the id=header? tried splitting it into 2 lines? $("#footer").width($("#grid").width()); $("#header").width($("#grid").width()); or use the variable?

Comment: no, it does work, it gets the width of the grid and applies it to the header, actually the selector is top-inner, but i guess that makes no difference, I updated the script to reflect that. I think I will try to contain the header in the masonry grid! Thanks

Comment: right, the other solution requires that you change the (html) layout so these components are in the right container, next time please give us a jsfiddle so we can take a look at the actual sourcecode parts with the corresponding css, javascript and html =)

Comment: sure i'll have a code next time. thanks for taking the time to help out :)